# Как подключить getID3 на сайт?

Tags: php, id3v2

https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3

Подключаю в корне сайта в `index.php`

Кроме этого кода ничего больше нет.

Файлы mp3 и getid3.php на своём месте.

```
<?php
    require_once('/getid3/getid3.php');
    $getID3 = new getID3;
    $filename='/2.mp3';
    $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);
    $getID3->CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);

    echo $ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['artist'][0]; 
    echo $ThisFileInfo['tags']['id3v2']['title'][0];  
    echo $ThisFileInfo['audio']['bitrate'];           
    echo $ThisFileInfo['playtime_string'];
?>
```

Получаю HTTP ERROR 500

Что не так?

Comment: открываем хром и https://i.stack.imgur.com/8edPO.png   затем https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hX7b.png

Comment: просто 500 никому ни о чём не говорит... нужно смотреть ответ ошибки

Comment: Ещё ответ можно посмотреть в логах сервера

Comment: Полные пути к файлам php и mp3 тоже прописывал

Comment: Не может быть такого чтобы ничего не было. 500 как и все ошибки - всегда дают текст. Тогда надо смотреть логи

Answer (score -1):

Прописать полные пути к файлам

```
$filename='/var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/1.mp3';
```

Comment: это некорректно. никогда нельзя использовать абсолютные пути. Как минимум потому что они мог поменяться. А во вторых применятся на разных системах. Только относительные.

Comment: И как быть? Относительные не работают.

Comment: Работают, просто надо корректно их прописать